# Kohana Template navigation, header or footer

Tags: php, templates, kohana

I am trying to get a navigation into my template.

Controller:

```
class Controller_Admin_Topnav extends Controller_Template {

    public $template = 'admin/template';

    public function action_index()
    {       
        $topnav = 566;
        $this->template->content = View::factory('admin/topnav')
            ->bind('topnav', $topnav);
    }

}
```

Template

```
    <?=View::factory('admin/topnav')?>
    <?= $content; ?>
```

View

```
    <?=$topnav?>
```

Error:
If i call domain/admin/topnav it works else not. I am getting this error.

```
ErrorException [ Notice ]: Undefined variable: topnav
```

What do i do wrong?

Thnx!

Comment: You have controller class as Controller_Admin_Topnav so it will work for 'domain/admin/topnav'.

Comment: Thats correct, only i want to include this in my template

Comment: This was the part of the solution.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8158017/how-to-manage-multiple-templates-and-template-assets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is binding some Views to the variables of the main template.

Example:

Main Template

```
<?php echo $navigation; ?>
<?php echo $content; ?>
```

Navigation Template

```
<p>This is the navigation</p>
```

Content Template

```
<p>This is the content of my website</p>
```

In the Controller

```
$this->template = View::factory('mainTemplate')
       ->bind('navigation', View::factory('navigationTemplate'))
       ->bind('content', View::factory('contentTemplate'));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use  path from controller: domain/admin/topnav it works because you are binding here $topnav variable

```
$this->template->content = View::factory('admin/topnav')
        ->bind('topnav', $topnav);
```

When you are rendering it in your template, there is no binding of $topnav variable so your topnav.php view is throwing error when rendering.

Just bind also $topnav variable here, for ex.

```
<?=View::factory('admin/topnav')
    ->bind('topnav', $topnav)?>
<?= $content; ?>
```

Of course declare $topnav first.